# How do i use an arduino controller and a keyboard at the same time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller, serial-port, arduino-uno, timeoutexception

How do I use a controller and keyboard at the same time?

So I use an Arduino as my controller using `ReadByte()` as my input
Here is my script for my player

```c#
void Start() 
{      
    controller = GetComponent<Controller2D>();  // Je krijgt toegang tot de script Controller2D
    sp.DtrEnable = true;
    sp.ReadTimeout = 100;       

    sp.Open();  // Uw serialpoort openen      
}

void Update() 
{
    if (sp.IsOpen)    // Als uw serialpoort open is
    {
        try
        {
            print(sp.ReadByte());   // Ga je de inkomende waarde lezen
        }
        catch (System.Exception) { }
    }      

    if (controller.collisions.above || controller.collisions.below)    // Als je een botsing hebt van boven of beneden dan ga je stoppen met springen
    {
        moveDistance.y = 0;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || sp.ReadByte() == 1 && controller.collisions.below)   // Als je op spatie drukt en als je op een platform staat dan ga je boven springen
    {
        moveDistance.y = jumpDistance;  // Je gaat springen langs de y-as
        //moveDistance.x = 0;     // Als je alleen springt dan ga je loodrecht boven en niet schuin
    }

    Vector2 input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));  // Je neemt de Horizontal en vertical inputs van de unity zelf

    if (sp.ReadByte() == 2)       // Als je de 2de drukknop indrukt
    {
        moveDistance.x = -moveSpeed ;   // Ga je links bewegen
    }
    if (sp.ReadByte() == 3)        // Als je de 3de druknop indrukt
    {
        moveDistance.x = moveSpeed;     // Ga je rechts bewegen
    }

    moveDistance.x = input.x * moveSpeed;   // Door input kan je nu links of rechts bewegen met de pijlen
    moveDistance.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;     // Je valt met een zwaartekracht dus je gaat sneller en sneller vallen.       
    controller.Move(moveDistance * Time.deltaTime);     // Leest de input 
}
```

Normally I would want to have both controller and keyboard as my inputs but after I run this game I immediatly get a

> TimeoutException: the operation has timed out

error but I can use the Arduino as inputs but it's just the keyboard that gets disabled for some reason

Comment: At which line do you get the exception?

Comment: I get an exception at every line that includes a sp.ReadByte

Comment: Giving a higher sp.ReadTimeout just makes the TimeoutException message come out slower for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be the cause of the error not sure but in general I would not use `sp.ReadByte()` repeatedly but only **once**, store the value and compare that:

```
void Update() 
{
    byte arduinoInput = 0;
    if (sp.IsOpen)    // Als uw serialpoort open is
    {
        try
        {
            arduinoInput  = sp.ReadByte();
            print(arduinoInput);   // Ga je de inkomende waarde lezen
        }
        catch (System.Exception) { }
    }      

    if (controller.collisions.above || controller.collisions.below)    // Als je een botsing hebt van boven of beneden dan ga je stoppen met springen
    {
        moveDistance.y = 0;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || arduinoInput == 1 && controller.collisions.below)   // Als je op spatie drukt en als je op een platform staat dan ga je boven springen
    {
        moveDistance.y = jumpDistance;  // Je gaat springen langs de y-as
        //moveDistance.x = 0;     // Als je alleen springt dan ga je loodrecht boven en niet schuin
    }

    Vector2 input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));  // Je neemt de Horizontal en vertical inputs van de unity zelf

    if (arduinoInput == 2)       // Als je de 2de drukknop indrukt
    {
        moveDistance.x = -moveSpeed ;   // Ga je links bewegen
    }
    if (arduinoInput == 3)        // Als je de 3de druknop indrukt
    {
        moveDistance.x = moveSpeed;     // Ga je rechts bewegen
    }

    moveDistance.x = input.x * moveSpeed;   // Door input kan je nu links of rechts bewegen met de pijlen
    moveDistance.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;     // Je valt met een zwaartekracht dus je gaat sneller en sneller vallen.       
    controller.Move(moveDistance * Time.deltaTime);     // Leest de input 
}
```

The errors are probably thrown for frames when the port is not open yet bt you already tried to read or simply caused by the multiple access.

Comment: This script is giving me 2 errors. byte arduinoInput = -1; gives me: *Constant value '-1' cannot be converted to a 'byte'* i tried fixing this by giving in byte arduinoInput; . And the line arduinoInput =  sp.ReadByte(); gives me: *Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*. I tried fixing this by casting back a byte like this arduinoInput =  (byte) sp.ReadByte(); but now it makes my game laggy which i can deal with but the biggest problem is that it doesn't read the inputs of my arduino anymore but it still prints the outputs

Comment: This did fix the TimeoutException error though which is nice

Comment: Found my problem i didn't copy the controller.Move line in my arduinoInput if statements